# How to login with Google+ api with iOS 6?

Tags: ipad, ios4, ios6, ios-simulator

Please give me a link to any tutorial for login via Google+ api.I am stuck.I alredy tried https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/ for that but after changing the clientID it continuously shows an error about invelid_scope on simulator.I need to integrate it in iOS 6.if you have any clue.Please give me feedback as soon as possible.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a compatible api towards the iOS 6.

Comment: Yes..If it is possible then please provide me.